# On ASP.NET textbox losing property after PostBack occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, viewstate

On my .aspx page I have certain fields that I want disabled so I flag these with a `carvedinstone` property and dynamically apply `disabled="disabled"` in the codebehind so the pre-populated value can't be changed by a user. **Note:** *This is legacy code 10+ years old so the "Why's?" can only be answered with "It was 2004, someone else did it this way, shrug".*

When a PostBack occurs during validation the `disabled="disabled"` property is removed from the fields that had it. I want to prevent that from happening.

**.aspx page**

```
<asp:TextBox
    ID="fEE_SSN"
    runat="server"
    alias="fSSN"
    prefix="[0]"
    strip="-"
    stripfor="both"
    width="160px"
    maxlength="11"
    carvedinstone="thirdparty" />
```

The .aspx page also has required field and regular expression validators:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
    ID="rfv_fSSN"
    runat="server"
    display="Dynamic"
    errormessage="Please enter the Employee's SSN"
    controltovalidate="fEE_SSN"
    cssclass="error"
    enabled="false">[*]</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    ID="rev_fSSN"
    runat="server" 
    display="Dynamic"
    errormessage="Please enter a valild SSN"
    controltovalidate="fEE_SSN"
    validationexpression="\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}"
    cssclass="error"
    enabled="false">[#]</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The function for applying `disabled="disabled"` is being called at `Page_Load`. `Page_Load` calls the `validateValidators()` method which calls the validation check where the disabling of the field happens:

**Page_Load() method**:

```
protected virtual void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SimpleTracer.Write(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " Begin");
    EnsureChildControls();
    validateValidators();
}
```

**validateValidators() method**:

```
protected virtual void validateValidators()
{
    foreach (BaseValidator validator in Validators)
    {
        if (!validator.Enabled)
            continue; // validator has already been disabled

        bool enable = validateValidator(validator, form);
        validator.Enabled = enable;
    }
}
```

**validateValidator() method**:

```
protected virtual bool validateValidator(BaseValidator validator, Control parent)
{
    WebControl control = null;

    if (validator is CustomValidator)
    {
        string controlId = validator.Attributes["checkboxgroupprefix"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(controlId))
            control = parent.FindControl(controlId + "1") as WebControl;
        else
            control = parent.FindControl(validator.ControlToValidate) as WebControl;

        if (control != null)
        {
            if (control.GetType().Name == "TextBox")
            {
                if (CheckCarvedInStoneControl(control))
                    return false;
            }
            if (control.GetType().Name == "RequiredFieldValidator")
            {
                if (CheckCarvedInStoneValidator(control))
                    return false;
            }
            if (IsReadOnlyForSubmissionType(control, m_SubmissionType))
                return false;
        }

        if (control == null && parent.HasControls())
        {
            foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
                if (!validateValidator(validator, child))
                    return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If anyone has any ideas how to preserve that property after PostBack I'd love to hear from you. Thanks, all!

Comment: Why not use TextBox's own property `Enabled = false`? Why such elaborate disabling?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter the only answer I could give is that someone felt at the time it was a better solution to do it in the codebehind.

Comment: So assign `fEE_SSN.Enabled = false;` in code behind instead of `fEE_SSN.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";` this way it will persist between postbacks

Comment: @YuriyGalanter that's pretty much how the `disabled="disabled"` property is getting applied to the field, where a check is being performed in the codebehind: `(webControl as TextBox).Enabled = false;`

Comment: After re-reading the question, clearly my answer was way off.  But I'm curious, why they aren't preserving, they really should be.  At what point in the page lifecycle are you updated the disabled property?

Comment: @Smeegs the function that does that is being called at `Page_Load` time. I just came across [this post](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Preserving-state-and-values-of-custom-properties-across-postback-in-ASP.Net.aspx) about preserving state and values of custom properties across PostBack in .NET. I'm a bit fuzzy on how to get it wired up with my code but I'll give anything a try.

Comment: Can you provide your Page_Load() code in addition to the markup.

Comment: @andleer I've updated it to show `Page_Load()` and the methods that are called that disable the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code inside your `Page_Load` method looks something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object send, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!PostBack)
    {
        // ... some unknown code here
        (webControl as TextBox).Enabled = false;
        // ... some unknown code here
    }
    // ... some unknown code here
}
```

then try moving the code that sets the `.Enabled` property outside of the `PostBack` check:

```
protected void Page_Load(object send, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!PostBack)
    {
        // ... some unknown code here
    }
    // ... some unknown code here
    (webControl as TextBox).Enabled = false;
}
```